# Javascript receipt printing using POS Printer

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

In a web application I want to print a receipt using a POS (Point of Sale) Printer. I want to do that with Javascript. Can anyone provide me an example for that?

Comment: Quite harsh demands, here... I which way are you able to print trough the POS-printer today? I believe you need some server-side handling (hence my suggestion would be a AJAX-call to a ServerSide-script doing the printing.

Comment: I think this is beyond the scope of JavaScript alone. You can do things like use JavaScript to help create an HTML document that's formatted for printing, and even launch the print dialog so that the user just clicks the "Print" button.... as long as the POS printer is installed on the PC and set as a option in the printer list. Printing requires drivers that work for that printer, and JS can't dive into the hardware of a machine unless you are running in an environment where there are API's available to tap into the hardware. But that won't happen in a browser.

Comment: Might be helpful if you provide some more info; What have you got so far? Do you just want to be able to print - or is this specific to POS? Google returned me quite a few examples of using JS to print.

Comment: Epson seems to be one of the only printers capable of this check out there ePOS Javascript SDK docs https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6046&scat=57&pcat=52

Comment: I saw this link for JS SDK on Epson website :https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&pcat=52&scat=57

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here , since your question was not very detailed, that 
a) your receipt printer is a thermal printer that needs raw data, 
b) that "from javascript" you are talking about printing from the web browser and 
c) that you do not have access to send raw data from browser

Here is a Java Applet that solves all that for you  , if I'm correct about those assumptions then you need either Java, Flash, or Silverlight 
     http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/

Comment: how about printing from a web browser in a mobile device like android?

Comment: @radztech - same situation there

Comment: https://github.com/qzind/tray/

Comment: @ErolGuzoğlu - that is still from the browser.  Not from the client code that is written as part of a website in javascript.  The browser running on the operating system can access a lot more that the javascript from a website which the browser is executing

Comment: @ScottSelby - the link provided by ErolGuzoğlu talks back to a client on the desktop which has access to the printers, etc.

Comment: now http://qz.io

Answer (score 13):

I have recently implemented the receipt printing simply by pressing a button on a web page, without having to enter the printer options. I have done it using **EPSON javascript SDK for ePOS**. I have test it on **EPSON TM-m30** receipt printer.

Here is the sample code.

```
var printer = null;
var ePosDev = null;

function InitMyPrinter() {
    console.log("Init Printer");

    var printerPort = 8008;
    var printerAddress = "192.168.198.168";
    if (isSSL) {
        printerPort = 8043;
    }
    ePosDev = new epson.ePOSDevice();
    ePosDev.connect(printerAddress, printerPort, cbConnect);
}

//Printing
function cbConnect(data) {
    if (data == 'OK' || data == 'SSL_CONNECT_OK') {
        ePosDev.createDevice('local_printer', ePosDev.DEVICE_TYPE_PRINTER,
            {'crypto': false, 'buffer': false}, cbCreateDevice_printer);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
}

function cbCreateDevice_printer(devobj, retcode) {
    if (retcode == 'OK') {
        printer = devobj;
        printer.timeout = 60000;
        printer.onreceive = function (res) { //alert(res.success);
            console.log("Printer Object Created");

        };
        printer.oncoveropen = function () { //alert('coveropen');
            console.log("Printer Cover Open");

        };
    } else {
        console.log(retcode);
        isRegPrintConnected = false;
    }
}

function print(salePrintObj) {
    debugger;
    if (isRegPrintConnected == false
        || printer == null) {
        return;
    }
    console.log("Printing Started");


    printer.addLayout(printer.LAYOUT_RECEIPT, 800, 0, 0, 0, 35, 0);
    printer.addTextAlign(printer.ALIGN_CENTER);
    printer.addTextSmooth(true);
    printer.addText('\n');
    printer.addText('\n');

    printer.addTextDouble(true, true);
    printer.addText(CompanyName + '\n');

    printer.addTextDouble(false, false);
    printer.addText(CompanyHeader + '\n');
    printer.addText('\n');

    printer.addTextAlign(printer.ALIGN_LEFT);
    printer.addText('DATE: ' + currentDate + '\t\t');

    printer.addTextAlign(printer.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    printer.addText('TIME: ' + currentTime + '\n');

    printer.addTextAlign(printer.ALIGN_LEFT);

    printer.addTextAlign(printer.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    printer.addText('REGISTER: ' + RegisterName + '\n');
    printer.addTextAlign(printer.ALIGN_LEFT);
    printer.addText('SALE # ' + SaleNumber + '\n');

    printer.addTextAlign(printer.ALIGN_CENTER);
    printer.addTextStyle(false, false, true, printer.COLOR_1);
    printer.addTextStyle(false, false, false, printer.COLOR_1);
    printer.addTextDouble(false, true);
    printer.addText('* SALE RECEIPT *\n');
    printer.addTextDouble(false, false);
....
....
....

}
```

Comment: I'm also using TM-88V from Epson. I think only Epson got such capability to print via Javascript.

Comment: @HAbin Sheikh did you used bluetooth variant or wifi variant? is it possible to print receipt from javascript in bluetooth variant?

Comment: it is possible to print with a TM T-20 by USB?

Comment: where does isSSL come from and why is the var isRegPrintConnected missing?

Comment: For this asking, Epson has a list of supported printers and interfaces for their ePOS Javascript SDK https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6046&scat=57&pcat=52

Comment: @teapeng agreed, right ePOS models of the Epson are supporting javascript printing

Comment: @JimVercoelen you need to add these variables if you copy exact code.

Comment: @HabibSheikh i am trying to print via Fiscal FP-81II RT but i am having some issues, i would really appreciate if you can give me an idea of it.

Comment: @HabibSheikh Did you test with a simulator and if yes, which one?

Answer (score 7):

If you are talking about a browser based POS app then it basically can't be done out of the box. There are a number of alternatives.

1. Use an applet like Scott Selby says
2. Print from the server. If this is a
   cloud server, ie not connectable to the receipt printer then what
   you can do is

   - From the server generate it as a pdf which can be made to popup a print dialog in the browser
   - Use something like Google Cloud Print which will allow connecting printers to a cloud service

Comment: Alternatively to PDF, content styled through CSS with `media="print"` will do the job.

Comment: Possibly. Can you turn off the headers and footers when you normally print a page and control the page size accurately with media="print" ?

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT: NOV 27th,  2017 ─ BROKEN LINKS**

Links below about the posts written by [David Kelley](https://medium.com/@davidkelley87/) **are broken**.

There are cached versions of the repository, just add `cache:` before the URL in the Chrome Browser and hit enter.

- 1st POST: [Cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdavidkelley%2Fdavidkelley.github.io%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2F_posts%2F2014-02-14-connecting-to-usb-device-using-javascript.markdown&oq=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdavidkelley%2Fdavidkelley.github.io%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2F_posts%2F2014-02-14-connecting-to-usb-device-using-javascript.markdown&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i60.2103j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) | [Medium Post](https://medium.com/@davidkelley87/javascript-interface-for-esc-pos-18123ead9219)
- 2nd POST: [Cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Lbs1HD8yj8wJ:https://github.com/davidkelley/davidkelley.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2014-02-14-connecting-to-usb-device-using-javascript.markdown&num=1&hl=en&gl=pe&strip=0&vwsrc=0)

---

> This solution is only for [**Google Chrome**](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb) and [**Chromium-based**](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/usb-api) browsers.

**EDIT:**

**(*)The links are broken. Fortunately I found [this repository](https://github.com/davidkelley/davidkelley.github.io) that contains the source of the post in the following markdown files: [A](https://github.com/davidkelley/davidkelley.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2014-02-14-connecting-to-usb-device-using-javascript.markdown) | [B](https://github.com/davidkelley/davidkelley.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2013-09-15-javascript-interface-for-esc-pos.markdown)**

<del>[This link](http://davidkelley.me/development/work/javascript/web/2013/08/31/javascript-interface-for-esc-pos.html)</del>* explains how to make a Javascript Interface for ESC/POS printers using Chrome/Chromium **USB API** [(1)](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb)[(2)](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb).
<del>[This link](http://davidkelley.me/development/work/javascript/web/chrome/2014/02/14/connecting-to-usb-device-using-javascript.html)</del>* explains how to Connect to USB devices using the `chrome.usb.*` API.

Comment: Looks like chrome.usb* api is available only for chrome extensions and not from javascript.

Comment: @FelipeAlarcon I'm sorry i don't have a copy of the contents of the link. Hopefully, someone here have a copy.

Comment: @FelipeAlarcon found the source! Answer is updated. :)

Answer (score 4):

I printed form javascript to a Star Micronics Webprnt TSP 654ii thermal printer. This printer is a wired network printer and you can draw the content to a HTML canvas and make a HTTP request to print. The only caveat is that, this printer does not support HTTPS protocol yet, so you will get a mixed content warning in production. Contacted Star micronics support and they said, they are working on HTTPS support and soon a firmware upgrade will be available. Also, looks like Epson Omnilink TM-88V printer with TM-I will support javascript printing.

Here is a sample code: https://github.com/w3cloud/starwebprint

Comment: Thermal printers capable of printing directly from javascript are expensive. Besides the mixed content warning is a bummer. So, I concluded  directly printing from javascript is not a good idea at this time. Instead, I utilized the media print tag and called the window.print to open the print dialog. Also, in kiosk mode, chrome can print without even showing print preview dialog. This is cool and pretty much the same effect as printing directly.

Comment: I have used these printers as well. The price is a bit annoying. I have spoken to Star and they say an update that supports HTTPS is coming.

Comment: I desperately need javascript html5 canvas printing. If any of you have tried Epson TM-20ii-I Omni link printer, please share your experience. Wish to know if it supports https or not.

Comment: I haven't tried this printer yet. I would like to test and support more printers but they are expensive!

Comment: i looked into this and the code. but idk what to use in the printer URL when the printer is connected via USBport

Comment: @KarthikSankar I am also wanted to use star micronics printer. I am using a SK1 printer connected to PC using a USB. How can i configure the localhost port to send the print command. ? I am stucked here .

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could have a look at this if your printer is an epson. There is a javascript driver

http://spsrprofessionals.com/ClientSite/readers/ePOS-Print_SDK_141020E/JavaScript/ePOS-Print_SDK_JS_en_revB.pdf

EDIT:

Previous link seems to be broken

All details about how to use epos of epson are on epson website:

https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_epos_device_js_en/index.php?content_id=139

Comment: The link you posted about EPSON's ePOS is broken.

Answer (score 1):

try Escpos
for PHP POS printing use
https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php

Answer (score 1):

You could try using https://www.printnode.com which is essentially exactly the service that you are looking for. You download and install a desktop client onto the users computer - https://www.printnode.com/download. You can then discover and print to any printers on that user's computer using their JSON API https://www.printnode.com/docs/api/curl/. They have lots of libs here: https://github.com/PrintNode/

Comment: is there a version of PrintNode you can host on your own server to assure privacy of your documents?