# Making a dynamic HTML table using json

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to create an HTML table using json data. The json data will change over time.  When convert this json data to HTML table, the table look like this with consistent. It means the alignment of money values and the width of the table. How can I convert the json data into HTML table?

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello</title>
      <style>
         table{
         font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
         }
         td#aliCenter{
         text-align:center;
         }
         td#aliRight{
         text-align:right;
         }
         td#myId{
         text-align:center;
         font-size: 13px;
         }

      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table width="302.362205"> <!-- To print paper size is 80 cm (=302.362205 pixel) -->
         <!-- header -->
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5" id="aliCenter">Moring Cafe<br>Main Road, Kandawala<br>Contact : 111-555-878</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5" id="myId">15/11/2018 16:14:52&nbsp;&nbsp;SAKTHY&nbsp;&nbsp;No: 24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
               <hr>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td id="aliCenter">NO</td>
            <td id="aliCenter">ITEM</td>
            <td id="aliCenter">QTY</td>
            <td id="aliCenter">PRICE</td>
            <td id="aliCenter">AMOUNT</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
               <hr>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <!-- buying items -->
         <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td colspan="4">Pizza</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>PZ4545</td>
            <td>2.00</td>
            <td id="aliRight">150.00</td>
            <td id="aliRight">300.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td colspan="4">Buggers</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>BR7878</td>
            <td>5.00</td>
            <td id="aliRight">500.00</td>
            <td id="aliRight">2500.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td colspan="4">Cock</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>CC6523</td>
            <td>3.00</td>
            <td id="aliRight">180.00</td>
            <td id="aliRight">540.00</td>
         </tr>
         <!-- footer -->
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
               <hr>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3">Net Total</td>
            <td id="aliRight">3340.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3">Cash</td>
            <td id="aliRight">3500.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3">Balance</td>
            <td id="aliRight">160.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5" id="aliCenter">-----------IMPORTANT NOTICE-----------</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5" id="aliCenter">In case of a price discrepancy, <br>return the bill and item within <br> 2 days to refund the difference</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

The json data contains main three parts. Such as header, items and footer. The header and footer is fixed, but the items's length will change over customers. The items should be circulate with the above table format, without changing the consistence.

```
{
    "header": {
        "invoice": "24",
        "name": "Morning Cafe",
        "address": "Main Road, Kandawala",
        "contact": "111-555-878",
        "date": "15/11/2018 16:14:52",
        "counter": "SAKTHY"
    },
    "items": [{
        "no": "1",
        "item": "Pizza",
        "code":"PZ4545",
        "price": "150.00",
        "qty":"2.00",
        "amount":"300.00"
    },
    {
        "no": "2",
        "item": "Burger",
        "code":"BR7878",
        "price": "500.00",
        "qty":"5.00",
        "amount":"2500.00"
    },
    {
        "no": "3",
        "item": "Cock",
        "code":"CC6523",
        "price": "180.00",
        "qty":"3.00",
        "amount":"540.00"
    }],
    "footer": {
        "total":"3340.00",
        "cash":"3500.00",
        "balance":"160.00",
        "notice": "In case of a price discrepancy, return the bill and item within 2 days to refund the difference."
    },
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @jmargolisvt, see the updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a plain JS solution. The JSON is parsed as a JSON object. I edited your HTML and added some new elements with an ID to select them from within JavaScript.

I edited my answer. NEVER use id multiple times. I changed it to a CSS class. Align should be correct now.

EDIT: Here is a single file solution: https://jsfiddle.net/e3xm1r05/2/

```js
var data = JSON.parse(`{
    "header": {
        "invoice": "59",
        "name": "Morning Cafe",
        "address": "Main Road, Kandawala",
        "contact": "111-555-978",
        "date": "12/11/2018 01:28:52",
        "counter": "SAKTHY"
    },
    "items": [{
        "no": "1",
        "item": "Pizza",
        "code":"PZ4566",
        "price": "500.00",
        "qty":"2",
        "amount":"1000.00"
    },
    {
        "no": "2",
        "item": "Burger",
        "code":"BR4587",
        "price": "250.00",
        "qty":"2",
        "amount":"500.00"
    },
    {
        "no": "3",
        "item": "Sample",
        "code":"SE2569",
        "price": "50.00",
        "qty":"5",
        "amount":"250.00"
    }],
    "footer": {
        "total":"1750.00",
        "cash":"2000.00",
        "balance":"250.00",
        "notice": "In case of a price discrepancy, return the bill and item within 2 days to refund the difference."
    }
    }`);

document.getElementById('invoice-name').innerHTML  = data.header.name;
document.getElementById('invoice-address').innerHTML  = data.header.address;
document.getElementById('invoice-contact').innerHTML  = data.header.contact;
document.getElementById('invoice-date').innerHTML  = data.header.date;
document.getElementById('invoice-counter').innerHTML  = data.header.counter;
document.getElementById('invoice-no').innerHTML  = data.header.invoice;

var insertAtRow=5;
var table = document.getElementById("invoice-table");
for(var i = data.items.length-1; i >=0 ;i--)
{
 var item = data.items[i];
  var rowHead = table.insertRow(insertAtRow);
 var rowItem = table.insertRow(insertAtRow+1);
 
  rowHead.insertCell(0).innerHTML = item.no;
  rowHead.insertCell(1).innerHTML = item.item;
  
  rowItem.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "";
 rowItem.insertCell(1).innerHTML = item.code;
 rowItem.insertCell(2).innerHTML = item.qty;
  
  var priceCell = rowItem.insertCell(3);
  var amountCell = rowItem.insertCell(4);
  priceCell.innerHTML = item.price;
  amountCell.innerHTML = item.amount;
  priceCell.classList.add('aliRight');
  amountCell.classList.add('aliRight');
}

document.getElementById('footer-net-total').innerHTML  = data.footer.total;
document.getElementById('footer-cash').innerHTML  = data.footer.cash;
document.getElementById('footer-balance').innerHTML  = data.footer.balance;
document.getElementById('footer-notice').innerHTML  = data.footer.notice;
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello</title>
      <style>
         table{
         font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
         }
         .aliCenter{
         text-align:center;
         }
         .aliRight{
         text-align:right;
         }
         td#myId{
         text-align:center;
         font-size: 13px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table id="invoice-table" width="302.362205"> <!-- To print paper size is 80 cm (=302.362205 pixel) -->
         <!-- header -->
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="aliCenter">
              <div id="invoice-name"></div>
              <div id="invoice-address"></div>
              <div id="invoice-contact"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5" id="myId"><span id="invoice-date"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="invoice-counter"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;No: <span id="invoice-no"></span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
               <hr>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="aliCenter">NO</td>
            <td class="aliCenter">ITEM</td>
            <td class="aliCenter">QTY</td>
            <td class="aliCenter">PRICE</td>
            <td class="aliCenter">AMOUNT</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
               <hr>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <!-- buying items -->
         <!--Script will insert after 6th row!!!-->
         <!-- footer -->
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
               <hr>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3">Net Total</td>
            <td class="aliRight"><span id="footer-net-total"></span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3">Cash</td>
            <td class="aliRight"><span id="footer-cash"></span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="3">Balance</td>
            <td class="aliRight"><span id="footer-balance"></span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="aliCenter">-------IMPORTANT NOTICE-----------</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="aliCenter"><span id="footer-notice"></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry!, Did you changed the code on my post? Because I did not see, at that time I also edited.

Comment: Why the `<hr>` lies two times before starting items, but not before the `Net Total` ?

Comment: Sorry, I started inserting the items one row too late. Should be fixed now. Can't test it myself, am on my mobile right now

Comment: Nicely working, Can I use this to print receipt with [EPSON TM-T82 Receipt](https://www.epson.com.sg/For-Work/Printers/POS-Printers/Epson-TM-T82-Thermal-POS-Receipt-Printer/p/C31CB10302)

Comment: Since this is a POS printer => it needs raw data (Characters only), so this is not possible. Maybe check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463787/javascript-receipt-printing-using-pos-printer)

Comment: So how can I use this to print with POS printer? jsPDF is useful?

Comment: No, POS Printer can only print raw data, that means you can only send alphanumeric characters. If you want to print HTML or PDF you need another printer. But I am no pro when it comes to that, you better ask someone else :/

Comment: Thank you and nice.

Comment: In the json, `total` has only two decimal points(`1750.00`), but in output it gets three decimal points(`1750.000`), why?

Comment: The HTML code had a 0 still in it. I removed it. Should work now.

Comment: Thank you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML file should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello</title>
      <style>
         table{
         font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
         }
         td#aliCenter{
         text-align:center;
         }
         td#aliRight{
         text-align:right;
         }
         td#myId{
         text-align:center;
         font-size: 13px;
         }

      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table width="302.362205" id="your_table_id"> <!-- To print paper size is 80 cm (=302.362205 pixel) -->
         <!-- header -->
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5" id="aliCenter">Moring Cafe<br>Main Road, Kandawala<br>Contact : 111-555-878</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5" id="myId">15/11/2018 16:14:52&nbsp;&nbsp;SAKTHY&nbsp;&nbsp;No: 24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
               <hr>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td id="aliCenter">NO</td>
            <td id="aliCenter">ITEM</td>
            <td id="aliCenter">QTY</td>
            <td id="aliCenter">PRICE</td>
            <td id="aliCenter">AMOUNT</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
               <hr>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <!-- buying items -->

         <script>
        var json_data = JSON.parse('{
    "header": {
        "invoice": "59",
        "name": "Morning Cafe",
        "address": "Main Road, Kandawala",
        "contact": "111-555-978",
        "date": "12/11/2018 01:28:52",
        "counter": "SAKTHY"
    },
    "items": [{
        "no": "1",
        "item": "Pizza",
        "code":"PZ4566",
        "price": "500.00",
        "qty":"2",
        "amount":"1000.00"
    },
    {
        "no": "2",
        "item": "Burger",
        "code":"BR4587",
        "price": "250.00",
        "qty":"2",
        "amount":"500.00"
    },
    {
        "no": "3",
        "item": "Sample",
        "code":"SE2569",
        "price": "50.00",
        "qty":"5",
        "amount":"250.00"
    }],
    "footer": {
        "total":"1750.00",
        "cash":"2000.00",
        "balance":"250.00",
        "notice": "In case of a price discrepancy, return the bill and item within 2 days to refund the difference."
    },
}');

//Items - You can simply hard code the header into your HTML
for (var i = 0;i<json_data["items"].length;i++){

    document.getElementById("your_table_id").innerHTML+="<tr><td>" + json_data["items"][i]["no"] + 
    "</td><td colspan='4'>" + json_data["items"][i]["item"] + 
    "</td></tr><tr><td></td><td>" + json_data["items"][i]["code"] + 
    "</td><td>" + json_data["items"][i]["price"] + 
    "</td><td>" + json_data["items"][i]["qty"] + 
    "</td><td>" + json_data["items"][i]["amount"] + 
    "</td></tr>" ;
}

//Then write some code to generate the footer.
document.getElementById("your_table_id").innerHTML+="<tr><td colspan='5'><hr></td></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan='3'>Net Total</td><td id='aliRight'>" + json_data["footer"]["total"] + "</td></tr><tr></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan='3'>Cash</td><td id='aliRight'>" + json_data["footer"]["cash"] + "</td></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan='3'>Balance</td><td id='aliRight'>" + json_data["footer"]["balance"] + "</td></tr><tr></tr><tr><td colspan='5' id='aliCenter'>-----------IMPORTANT NOTICE-----------</td></tr><tr><td colspan='5' id='aliCenter'>" + json_data["footer"]["notice"] + "</td></tr>";
     </script>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Last two `<td>`s ? It means `qty` and `amount` ?

Comment: Please see my update json data according to the html content

Comment: How to add header and footer, It would appreciated

Comment: Alright I updated my answer. Just keep the header HTML you already have, but make sure to give your table an ID

Comment: Sorry!, I wrap the code inside the `<script> </script>` and put it around the html file. But not works

Comment: If you can't figure it out, I can just give you an entire HTML file to copy and paste, but you really should learn how to do this

Comment: Never mind. You already marked a different solution as correct, so I assume you have a working system now.

Comment: I checked with body tag also, but does not wok. Anyway if you give the entire HTML file, it will useful, because of your code is less than other, please.

Comment: Alright, I just realized I made a simple mistake. I simply had to parse the JSON

Comment: Alright, I worked out all the bugs and tested it. The update I just posted should work: I tested it on Chromium browser.

Comment: Thank you now it works, but header and footer is missing

Comment: Thank yo so much.