# How to print from web application to pos printer using react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing, epson, pos

I was trying to connect and print the data on my POS printer programmatically. My printer is TM-U220 with USB port only. I went through the epson SDK for javascript but it only allowing me to connect via LAN (i.e. using IP and Port only). Is there any way that I can connect my JS code with POS printer using printer name because my printer does not have any lan port with it. Attaching some stack overflow link below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44660273

POS Javascript SDK Link: https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6679&scat=57&pcat=52

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your backend should be able to print directly. You cannot access printing hardware from JS other than indirectly by using window.print()

Comment: @ChrisG How can I connect with my backend directly to printer if my api are hosted on different server and my printer is in other network? Any link or guideline will be really helpful.

Comment: Right, you probably can't. You could share the printer on the network and use a VPN connection between the printer's computer and the server though. Seems all very convoluted; how is the USB printer commonly used? POS software?

Comment: @ChrisG Not sure mostly yes